# no way to stop a page from being cached

Tags: php, header

I'am using firefox 21 and would like to prevent the browser to cache a soundfile.
I send this data to the browser:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate',true); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

$test = $path.$filename; 

<audio autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="<? echo $test; ?>" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

On the server I changing the filename and/or the content of the file.
The browser do not update the sound by reload the page.
Is there something wrong with the header?

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively setting the caching for your html document and not for your mp3 file.

However, if you want to force a reload, you can add a query string, for example like:

```
$test = $path . $filename . '?' . time();
```

Comment: I think than I get an error message "Header already been sent".
(Adding a timestamp is a good idea)

Comment: @hamburger That depends on whether you are displaying errors, like I said, the context is missing (including the error handling) so it's hard to tell from the code you posted.

Comment: thats my first lines:
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate',true); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 

echo "Start"."<br>";
It's an utf-8 file without bom

Comment: @hamburger You are setting the caching for your html document, not for your mp3 file.

Comment: How can I set it to my mp3 file?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you add this in your .htaccess file to prevent caching

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType audio/mp3 "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two resources: the HTML page and the mp3 file. Sending "don't cache" headers with the HTML won't help. The *mp3 file* response must have the "don't cache" headers.